# Is there something other than Notepad to write my HTML code?

Tags: html

How can I write HTML code and save it so that it looks just like what I wrote?
I used to use Notepad, but now when you save your code document, it moves all the lines one right after the other.  It looks like a run-on sentence and is very hard to read.  All of my spaces are gone.  It didn't used to do this.  Is there any other software that I can use to write my own codes and save so that it looks the same (with all my spaces for easier reading)?

Comment: I suggest that you try a more friendly & functional text editor, such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Comment: Get gVim.  All the cool kids use a vi-based editor.

Comment: If you want something more than just a text editor, you could check out Visual Studio Express 2012.  It is free, and has a really decent editor for both HTML and JavaScript with intellisense.  More information is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537667.aspx#installing_visual_web_developer_express You will also probably want to direct your programing related questions over to http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: [List of HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors)

Comment: Notepad++ is the best. I tried Notepad once and about threw a fit!

Answer (score 2):

That sounds really odd. Maybe you disabled the word wrapping in Notepad? There might as well be something off with your linebreaks. *A screenshot might be very helpful to solve this.*

As you didn't name your operating system, I'm assuming you're talking about Windows Notepad. It's enough to write code, but you might want to have a look at one or two more advanced editors (both being freeware):

- As alternatives, if you'd like it simple but powerful, go with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). This provides you with basic syntax highlighting (e.g. easier to see tags) and is perfectly fine if a text editor is all you need.
- If you'd like a (in my opinion) very nice combination of source code highlighting as well as real time preview/wysiwyg editor for free, have a look at [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads). This offers you a text editor and additional controls, for example it's very comfortable to edit stylesheets with a GUI editor (picking settings, colors, etc.).